# How to add object with expensive dtor to vector without emplace_back()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, raii

I have an object `RenderBuffer` that creates an OpenGL Buffer as part of it's constructor, and destroys it as part of it's destructor.  It's a very expensive operation.  This object has no default constructor, so it's either usually put in an initialization list or pushed into the back of a vector if there's many of them:

```
Window::Window(Renderer & render)
    : m_renderBuffer(render) // sometimes looks like this
{
    m_multipleBuffer.push_back(RenderBuffer(render)) // othertimes can look like this
}
```

the latter instance with the vector causes the destructor to be called, causing problems.

I am using VS2010 which lacks the `emplace_back()` that would make this work.  What can I do?  Should I abandon the RAII type of coding style and give my classes an `init(...)` method?  Is there a way to get this working with copy constructors?  And if there is, is it worth the effort over just using initialization methods (move constructors for each class would be a lot of boilerplate)?

Comment: `push_back` normally has a rvalue reference constructor, which allows it to be moved. Bear in mind though that VS2010 doesn't implement C++11 (or only has partial support), so this might not happen.

Comment: Store object by smart pointer

Comment: @jaggedSpire - I'd like to keep them contagious in memory if I can, since they're iterated over for each drawn object in a frame

Comment: @AnneQuinn then can you use boost.container? It seems like that library contains a number of vector-like containers, with move support and emulated move support for before C++11.

Comment: Can you use 'placement new' as a crude substitute for emplace_back()?

Comment: It sounds like you broke the rule-of-3 (or rule-of-5). Have you implemented a copy c-tor and assignment operator in your class? Also, consider adding a move c-tor and move assignment operator too for allowing an efficient move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply provide your own version of a move constructor. For example, you can provide a constructor which takes an additional "move" flag, and when the copy constructor is called for an object which has this flag set, it just performs a move instead of a copy.

This technique was described by Bjarne Stroustrup in [his keynote](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) at Going Native 2012, when asked how C++ developers implemented moves before C++11.

Also, while I haven't worked with this particular library, there is [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/move.html) which emulates move semantics for C++03 compilers. Movable classes get special move constructors and move assignment operators which are distinguished by having a `BOOST_RV_REF(T)` argument and which are called using `T a(boost::move(b))` or `T a = boost::move(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a vector of smart pointers to the object.  For example:

```
vector<shared_ptr<RenderBuffer> >  m_multipleBuffer;
```

Of course that means you have to dereference the pointer when you need the actual RenderBuffer which may or may not be practical depending on the rest of  your program, but if it *is* practical you can avoid unnecessary copy construction and destruction of RenderBuffer.

Note that the copy constructor is likely to be an expensive operation, too, unless the RenderBuffer is designed to share the underlying OpenGL Buffer.

Comment: By the way, keeping the objects in contiguous memory for performance reasons is over-rated.  I've done a lot of profiling in this type of situation and rarely do the perceived benefits of contiguous allocation outweigh the cost of enforcing that restriction.